# The 'build' tick mark missing from my copy of VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The 'build' tick mark that should appear in the bottom left of the VScode screen is not there.

I've reinstalled twice: once with the zip and once with the 'user' version with no luck.

I'm trying to compile firmware for my 3D printer but can't do the build without the tick mark.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a plug-in.  go to RUN - ADD CONFIGURATION - INSTALL EXTENSION - choose PLATFORMIO IDE

Had the same issue and this solved it.